Replace and redline certain substrings from a paragraph in Word using Office.js in Add-In
I have a paragraph present in the Word (Office 365). I can replace the whole paragraph, but I wanted to replace and redline only certain substrings in the paragraph.
Note:- By redline, I mean that the substring is to be open for review from the user.

For example, consider this paragraph:-
Actual paragraph

Greenhouse gases (GHGs) play a crucial role in regulating Earth's temperature by trapping heat in the atmosphere.

Updated paragraph

Greenhouse gases (GHGs) are pivotal in regulating Earth's temperature by trapping heat in the atmosphere.

Here in this scenario, I have only one updation for the whole paragraph i.e. play a crucial role to be replaced with are pivotal.
How can I achieve the above using a Word Office add-in?
Please consider the case that I cannot search and replace as different places may have different replacement strings and some of the places might not require any replacement.
Sample code which I have tried until now includes replacement of the whole paragraph, which results in the whole paragraph into the redline state.

await Word.run(async (context) => {
      let paragraphIndex = 10;
      let text = 'The new content';
      const paragraphs = context.document.body.paragraphs;
      paragraphs.load("items, count");
  
      await context.sync();
      
      paragraphs.items[paragraphIndex].insertText(text, Word.InsertLocation.replace);
  
      await context.sync();
});


Variable replacement strings, depending on context, reminds me of this sample: Word-Add-in-Angular2-StyleChecker and the way it uses the compareLocationWith method.

Hi @RickKirkham, thanks for the comment but this repo didn't helped.

There is a new set of word api requirement set 1.7 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/word/word-api-1-7-requirement-set?view=common-js-preview of annotations api for writing assistant scenarios, should be a right solution for you. Feel free to have a try.
